# How to prevent UI thread from entering model in WPF MVVM application?

Tags: c#, async-await, ui-thread

I'd like to establish a rule in my application architecture that no code in model objects should execute on the UI thread. The question is, how do I enforce this?

In C# using async/await, which thread something is executed on is generally determined by the caller. So if a user clicks a button, the event handler is running on the UI thread and it calls into my view model. In the view model, I want the developer to do something like call `Task.Run()` when calling methods on the model. But this is easy to forget. There are also non-obvious loopholes like raising an event that has been wired up to a listener that is a model object. Ideally, when a developer makes this kind of programming mistake, an exception would be thrown as soon as the UI thread tries to execute the method on the model. What I'd really like is a way to mark the assembly containing the model classes in a way that causes any method in it to throw an exception as soon as it is entered by the UI thread. The closest I've been able to come up with is to add a debug assertion at the beginning of every method to check the thread and fail if it is the UI thread. However, that litters the code with ugly checks and is another thing that can be forgotten.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I don't need to make it *impossible*. I just need to make it easy to do correctly and identify when it is done incorrectly. To put it into the pit of success.

Comment: Generally, it's ill-advised to run heavy back-end operations on the UI thread, like the producing / fetching / processing of data that typically happens in functions in the model. However, I see no need to prevent a UI thread from simply fetching the resulting stored data _from_ the model to utilise it on the UI.

Comment: @Nyerguds I agree, simply fetching wouldn't be a big deal. But clearly delineating whether that is what is happing is a problem. Proper encapsulation and abstraction through interfaces mean you don't really know what the implementation of some method does. This particular app does lots of hardware control using async. It is really easy for some operation to end up waiting on a hardware interaction.

Comment: When I make apps with multithreading, I generally make one "run this operation threaded" function which gets the function (from the UI class) to execute, with all parameters included, as `Action` argument. The function itself, on a new thread, will then call whatever model stuff it needs to call, and use `Invoke` to update the results on the UI. Of course, I have no idea whatsoever what kind of application you're making.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how do I enforce this?

You do not. There is no way to enforce a logical separation of concerns via  simple language rules.

The best way you can do is write an analyzer for this point that shows a warning in Visual Studio. BUT... have fun with that, I see this as an overly complex task not worth the time.

Comment: You say there is "no way to enforce a logical separation of concerns via simple language rules." But for example, you can put different layers in different projects and use the limitations on circular references to prevent calling into a layer you shouldn't. Although in theory, a dev can just put some code in the wrong project. That is much more obvious to them and a code reviewer than just forgetting Task.Run() somewhere it is needed. Just an example to say, you can with some kinds of logical separation.

Comment: You can, but this is not FORCING it, and the question is about enforcing it.